# Excel2010のマクロを実行時Just-In-Time (JIT) デバッグを呼び出してしまう

Tags: excel

win10 pro環境にて、マクロでデータ集計するツール作成しました。正常に稼働しました。しかし、そのツールをwin7proで実行すると、以下のエラーが発生し、処理が正常に終了できなくなりました。
再度、win10環境で試しても、問題なく動いていました。原因は全く分かりません。
Office: Professional Plus 2010 です。

Double型の変数は定義しておりません。

是非教えて頂きたいと思います。
宜しくお願い致します。

[image]

Comment: 実際のマクロの内容を質問文に含めてもらうことは可能ですか？後からでも [編集] できますので、必要に応じて追記してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。マクロ内容は複数の端末に接続し、対象となるファイルの中身を読み取って、結果を集計するものです。因みに、Double型の変数を使っていません。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: cubickさんが言われているのは、マクロのソースの開示です。守秘義務等あるとは思いますが、マクロのソースもなく発生した例外のみで原因を究明するのは困難を極めると思います。質問者さんがDouble型の変数は使っていないと言われていますが、直接使っていないだけで、Double型の値を処理している可能性もあり得ますので。Windows7Pro環境でデバッグした際にエラーになったあたりだけでも開示できないでしょうか。

Comment: ２つの環境(Win10pro, win7pro)それぞれで、使っているExcelのバージョンと32bit版/64bit版の別、有効にしているaddinのリストを教えて下さい。同じマクロ(VBAのプログラム）の動作が異なるというのですから、その原因はExcel自体か、その周辺(addin等）にあると思われますので。